# Sending email with html template with images to gmail,exchange

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-email

I am using the attached code to send email and images. It is working with gmail.
Now, I want to send to email using html templates. How do I use the attached code to do it?

```html
private void SendEmail1()
        {
            string strMailContent = "Welcome new user";
            string fromAddress = "xxx";
            string toAddress = "xxx";
            string contentId = "image1";
            string path = Server.MapPath(@"Images/ml2.png"); // my logo is placed in images folder
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress);
            mailMessage.Subject = "Welcome new User";

            LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource(path,"image/png");
            logo.ContentId = "companylogo";
            // done HTML formatting in the next line to display my logo
            AlternateView av1 = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<html><body><img src=cid:companylogo/><br></body></html>" + strMailContent, null, "text/html");
            av1.LinkedResources.Add(logo);

            mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(av1);
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

                       
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"];
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);


            smtp.Send(mailMessage);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your html isn't formatted correctly

```
AlternateView av1 = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<html><body><img src=cid:companylogo/><br></body></html>" + strMailContent, null, "text/html");
```

Should be

```
AlternateView av1 = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString($"<html><body><img src=cid:companylogo/><br>{strMailContent}</body></html>", "text/html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your html isn't formatted correctly and you're passing in a `null` encoding.

```
        AlternateView av1 = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<html><body><img src=cid:companylogo/><br></body></html>" + strMailContent, null, "text/html");
```

Should be

```
        AlternateView av1 = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString($"<html><body><img src=cid:companylogo/><br>{strMailContent}</body></html>", "text/html");
```